# There are exactly two ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}] \to \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $ d \in \mathbb{N} $ be a number that is not a square, i.e., $ d \neq a^{2} $ for all $ a \in \mathbb{N} $. We define
> $
> \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]:=\{a+b \sqrt{d} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}
> $.
> This is a subring of $ \mathbb{R} $ (no need to show that). Let $ R $ be another ring containing $ \mathbb{Q} $ as a subring.
>
> 1. Show that there are exactly two ring homomorphisms
>    $$
>    \varphi: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}] \,.
>    $$
> 2. Is there a ring homomorphism
>    $$
>    \varphi: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \,?
>    $$
>    Justify the answer carefully!

I’m having a hard time with these two problems right now, because I don’t really know how to show it. Do I have to find suitable homomorphisms first to show this? And how can I say in general for (1) that there are only two such ring homomorphisms?

Any advice on how to approach these tasks?

Comment: Hint: If $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, what it does to rational numbers? And what are the possible values of $\varphi(\sqrt{d})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt d]\to\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt d]$, you can easily check (by definition of ring homomorphism) that

- $\phi(n)=n$ for all integers $n$
- $\phi(1/m)=1/m$ for all integers $m$

Therefore $\phi(r)=r$ for any rational $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $\phi(r+s\sqrt d)=r+s\phi(\sqrt d)$. This means that $\phi$ is uniquely determined by $x:=\phi(\sqrt d)$.
Now, we have:
$$d=\phi(d)=\phi((\sqrt d)^2)=\phi(\sqrt d)\phi(\sqrt d)=x^2$$
Hence $x$ must be a square root of $d$ (more precisely, $x$ is such that $x^2=d$), i.e. $x=\sqrt d$ or $x=-\sqrt d$.

For the second point, any such homomorphism maps $\sqrt 3$ into a square root of $3$, but there are no square roots of $3$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2]$. Hence the homomorphism cannot exist.

Intuitively, "being a square root of $d$" is an algebraic property that must be preserved by any homomorphism